# Не получается обновить таблицу пользователя

Tags: php, laravel

хочу обновить таблицу, сделав поиск по id авторизованного пользователя, но этого почему-то не происходит. Даже не могу понять в чем проблема...

```
Order::create($request->all());
    if(Auth::check())
    {
        $authUser = Auth::user();
        User::where('id', $authUser->id)->update(['ordersAmount' => $authUser->ordersAmount + 1]);
    }
    return back();
```

Answer (score 0):

Советую так не делать.
Либо:

```
Auth::user()->ordersAmount++;
Auth::user()->save();
```

Либо чисто Fluent DB:

```
DB::table('users')->where('id', Auth::user()->id)->update([...]);
```

Если вы используете модели то нет смысла прописывать самому что-то даже если есть такая возможность. Здесь проблема может быть в том что update из модели не применяет изменения в  бд.

Comment: оба способа не работают(
Во втором случае выдает ошибку Trying to get property of non-object
Дело в том, что в другом контроллере все работает, а в этом нет. Почему - не понимаю....

Comment: @ВладиславТалах Проверяй при помощи хелпера dd() где что лежит. Не пустые  ли модели, не вернулось ли null и тд. По строчке

Comment: проверил через dd(Auth::user()). Почему-то null...

Comment: в любом другом контроллере все работает, а в этом нет. Бред какой-то

Comment: @ВладиславТалах значит пользователь не авторизован :) Ты меня что-то в этом плане? Может переделывал аунтефикацию из коробки, и где-то что-то подпортил. В любом случае если у тебя есть ID пользователя ты можешь сделать так:
`Auth::login($user);`
И тогда по-любому в Auth будет лежать пользователь :) Но это немного костыльно. По факту если у тебя возвращается null от пользователя значит у тебя он не авторизован. Проверь, в конструкторе контроллера должно быть обязательно `$this->middleware('auth');` т.е. доступ только авторизованным.

Comment: @ВладиславТалах и вообще, если у тебя Auth::user() это  null то ты никогда не пройдешь проверку на Auth::check() что очевидно, и твой код в блоке if не выполнится.